# Can one class implement both subject and observer sections of the observer design pattern?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I'm designing an enemy framework for java and working with observer. I'm wondering if it is possible | worth the effort to have one class implement both observer and subject in java?

I want to have an enemy interface which implements both subject and observer so that the enemies within a certain distance of each other can alert each other if a player or enemy is sighted.

Is there a better pattern to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of these would be slightly more appropriate to use than observer pattern, depending on actually how you want to implement your framework:

- [Implicit Invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_invocation)
- [Event-Driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)
- [Publish-Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)

The trouble with subject / observer is that they involve registering / deregistering when your enemies move in / out of range of each other.

I would recommend implicit invocation or event-driven as follows:

- Each time an enemy sights a player, generate an "event" that gets broadcast to all other enemies.
- This event will have a coordinate to specify from where it was broadcasted.
- For each enemy that receives the event (which is all of them), look at the coordinate and see if it's within a certain range of itself

  - If not, ignore it (and pretend as if it never heard it)
  - If so, do something as required.

Comment: @LinuxN00b: np =) consider accepting this answer if you've found it helpful to your question